# reading in a file separated by bars c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying trying to read in a file in C++ where the characters are separated by bars "|",
what is the best way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide a sample of the input you are describing? Also, how should newlines be treated in the input? As record separators, or as data inside a field?

Comment: Read it in like you would any other file. Or rephrase your quesiton.

Comment: Can you tell us if this is a homework assignment? We don't mind answering homework questions, but we answer them differently than work or play questions.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that fields are separated by bars, but records are separated by newlines.

First, read in the lines of text using `std::getline`:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

Then, break the line at `|` boudaries.

```
std::stringstream sline(line);
std::string field;
std::getline(sline, field, '|');
...
std::getline(sline, field, '|');
```

Comment: OP, if you're reading in a file, use the name of your file stream instead of cin

Comment: @Robotnik, I concur. Also, if the OP indicates that this isn't homework, I'll put up a more complete code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the code you're using, what you're looking for is a variation on a CSV (comma seperated value) file reader. There are thousands out there and if your code needs to be robust I'd suggest you use one of them rather than writing your own as there are complexities such as:

- What if one of your 'values' actually contains a '|' character in
  quotes say?
- What if one of your 'values' contains a carriage return
  or line feed?

One of the most popular is the [Boost tokeniser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) which should be pretty easy to get up and working with. You just need to ensure that you tell the tokeniser that you're using a '|' as a field seperator.

Take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c) for some more pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a file called "file.dat"
It looks like this:

```
item1|item2|item3|item4|item5|item6
```

This program will print each item in the file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main(){

    std::ifstream infile("file.dat");

    std::string item;
    getline(infile,item,'|');

    while (!infile.eof()){
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
        getline(infile,item,'|');
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I never recommend using `.eof()` as a loop condition. It almost always produces buggy code. Although your code seems to be the exception, I'd still recommend the easier-to-read: `std::string item; while(std::getline(infile, item, '|')) { std::cout << item << "\n"; }`